# CardboardView and Custom Menu Android

Tags: java, android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Im trying to use cardboard view (found example in internet)

```
private class CardboardOverlayEyeView extends ViewGroup {
        private final ImageView imageView;
        private final TextView textView;
        private float offset;

        public CardboardOverlayEyeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            imageView = new ImageView(context, attrs);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);  // Preserve aspect ratio.
            addView(imageView);

            textView = new TextView(context, attrs);
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 14.0f);
            textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setShadowLayer(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, Color.DKGRAY);
            addView(textView);
        }

        public void setColor(int color) {
            imageView.setColorFilter(color);
            textView.setTextColor(color);
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            textView.setText(text);
        }

        public void setTextViewAlpha(float alpha) {
            textView.setAlpha(alpha);
        }

        public void setOffset(float offset) {
            this.offset = offset;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
           //bla bla view positions.
        }
    }
}
```

I want to  add menu here for gamepad (via bluetooth). I just write another `layout.xml` with my menu and in `CardboardOverlayEyeView` using inflate i add this layout to my current viewGroup. But for correct work - `extends ViewGroup` was changed to `extends RelativeLayout`.

My menu showing good. There are few buttons like "point 1, point 2, point 3"
when im using controls on joystick (UP/DOWN) its on leftView showing focus (like another color for button)- and its good.But in right view no focus.Also But if im using control on joystic left/right - i can switch from left to right view . 
I want to remove switch and if leftView has focused button (with another color) i also want this steps in rightView. Can any one help me? how to do it.
[image]
picture

Comment: someone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly i did it.
simple part of code . Where we need array of buttons as a copy of main buttons from left and right view.

```
public void setFocusedButton() {
        for(int i=0; i<mLeftView.btns.length;i++){
            if(mLeftView.btns[i].isFocused() || mRightView.btns[i].isFocused()) {
                mLeftView.btns[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                mRightView.btns[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
            }else {
                mLeftView.btns[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
                mRightView.btns[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
            }
        }

    }
```

its not full focused. But its looks great.